# Trying to make my website be response

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm rather new to css and I'm working as an intern right now. I've been assigned the task to take a website's css from chrome and make it look similar in IE, then make it responsive and scaleable. So basicly if i make the window smaller, I want everything to stay the same, just to be smaller, and then when i make it bigger again, the text gets bigger. I've completed the transformation to IE, but the examples I find, works in Chrome and FF, but ofc not in IE..

Any idea on where i start making this??

```
html, body {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #8FAE9F;
font-family: Trebuchet MS;
font-size: 27px;
font-weight: bold;
height: 99%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}
.column.OBJ0, .column.OBJ1 {
max-width: 12.0em;
margin-right: -1.2em;
margin-left: -1.2em;
}
.blueBorder, .thresholds {
margin: 0;
padding: 5px;
width: 98%;
}
.thresholds {
display: inline;
float: left;
}
.Threshold_NONE {
color: black;
}
.Threshold_INFO {
color: green;
}
.Threshold_WARNING {
color: yellow;
}
.Threshold_ALERT {
color: red;
}
.Threshold_INFO, .Threshold_WARNING, .Threshold_ALERT, .Threshold_NONE {
font-size: 5em;
}
.displayText {
}
.column {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: text-top;
line-height: normal;
white-space: nowrap;
}
.header {
color: black;
font-size: 3em;
margin-left: -4px;
margin-right: -4px;
margin-top: -4px;
max-height: 1em;
}
.columnwrapper {
min-width: 378px;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 25%;
}
.displayAgent {
}
.displayAgent img {
float: left;
margin-bottom: auto;
margin-right: 0.5em;
margin-top: auto;
}
.displayAgent1 {
}
.displayAgent2 {
background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
.displayAgentName {
display: table;
text-align: right;
}
.displayAgentStatusImg {
padding-left: 0.5em;
}
.displayAgentStatus {
display: inline;
width: 71px;
}
.displayAgentStateTime {
display: inline;
width: 61px;
}
.displayAgentStatus_LoggedIn {
}
.displayAgentStatus_NotReady {    
}
.displayAgentStatus_Ready {
}
.displayAgentStatus_Reserved {
}
.displayAgentStatus_LoggedOut {
}
.displayAgentStatus_Talking {
}
.displayAgentStatus_Working {
}
div .displayAgentStateTime {
display: none;
}
div .displayAgentStatus {
display: none;
}
.PoweredBy {
bottom: 10px;
display: none;
font-size: 0.8em;
padding: 5px;
position: fixed;
right: 10px;
}
.lastupdate {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
display: table;
font-size: 1.2em;
margin-top: 0;
width: 7em;
}
.viewerDisplayItemErrorPanel {
color: red;
font-weight: bold;
}
.headline.remedyItem {
font-weight: bold;
}
.remedyItem span {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 1em;
max-height: 1.2em;
overflow: hidden;
}
div.headline.remedyItem {
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 4px solid;
}
span.remedyId {
width: 6em;
}
span.remedyCustomer {
width: 6em;
}
span.remedyPriority {
width: 2em;
}
span.remedyCaseTitle {
text-align: left;
width: 17em;
}
span.remedySLA {
width: 5em;
}
span.remedySubSlaType {
display: none;
}
span.remedyHidden {
}
span.remedyShowSLA {
width: 4em;
}
span.remedyGroup {
width: 6em;
}
div.column.Remedy {
clear: left;
margin-top: 0.5em;
}
div.column.Remedy h2 {
display: none;
}
div.uccx_exchange_user span.exchangeStatus {
display: none;
}
div.uccx_exchange_user span.uccxStatus {
display: none;
}

div.uccx_exchange_user span.user {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 1em;
width: 3.9em;
}
div.uccx_exchange_user {
max-height: 0.92em;
}
div.uccx_exchange_user img {
margin-top: 0.2em;
padding: 0;
}
.viewerDisplayItemShowPanel.øst {
clear: right;
float: right;
text-align: left;
}
.viewerDisplayItemShowPanel.vest {
clear: left;
float: left;
text-align: right;
margin-left: 1.5em;
}
.viewerDisplayItemShowPanel.øst div img {
float: center;
margin-left: -5.6em;
margin-right: 0.0em;
}
.viewerDisplayItemShowPanel.vest div img {
float: center;
margin-left: -0.8em;
margin-right: 0.1em;
}

.column h2.header {
font-size: 2.0em;
margin: 0;
}
.headline.remedyItem .remedyPriority {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
display: none;
}
.headline.remedyItem .remedyCustomer {
margin-right: 3em;
}
span.NOT_SET {
color: white;
}
div.FIX_AT_NONE .remedyId {
color: yellow;
}
span.NORMAL_ALERT, span.FIX_AT_ALERT {
color: red;
}
span.NORMAL_WARNING, span.FIX_AT_WARNING {
color: yellow;
}
span.NONE_WARNING, span.NONE_NONE {
color: blue;
}
span.NONE_ALERT {
color: purple;
}
.BURNED {
color: red;
}
.P1.remedyPriority {
background-color: red;
}
.P2.remedyPriority {
background-color: yellow;
}
span.RESPECTED {
color: green;
}
span.remedyUserLoginID {
display: none;
}
span.penaltyOn {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which versions of IE are you targeting?

Also i'd assume you're nesting HTML tags, using EM's is based off the font size of the parent not the body, maybe try using REM's instead?

I'd suggest reading up on this: http://css-tricks.com/confused-rem-em/

Could you post your HTML too?

Comment: The newest, so I guess that'd be 11 :) Not sure what nesting HTML tags mean, but I'm only touching the css, that's the only job, haven't gotten the HTML my self, besides F12 :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things in your questions one is making it IE compatible and 2nd is making it responsive.

For responsive part as you mentioned looks like you just want to make everything smaller for which you can define styles in % but that won't be called a responsive website as everthing will just be scaled and won't be readable or user-friendly.

Responsive on the other hand means to change the layout as well by using media queries while making everything easily readable by the user and converting things like hover events to touch events so it is also accessible on touch screen devices.

So it would be great if you can clear your requirements. If you just need something to fit then stick to %s or try media queries for making it fully responsive :)

Comment: Well what the company wants is to have perhaps, 2 different windows open at the same time. Then, since they have to scale them down to fit both on one screen, they want everything to stay on the same spot as it is when it's fullscreen, just everything a bit smaller ofcourse so it fits. So I want everything to stay at the same spot, but just smaller.

Comment: then you should use % for layout and EM for font sizes that would be enough and to stop everything from being unreadable you can define a minimum width to your website like 768px or something else you think your client will be happy with.

Comment: Yeah but how exactly do i do that, cause it's the first time i'm really digging deep into css to be honest, usually i'm programming :)

Comment: you should look into some basic HTML/CSS tutorials they would clear a lot of things for you :) You will also have to go through your CSS and see what elements have fixed dimensions in pixels then change them one by one. I know its a lot of work and also by my experience it is much harder to convert a website to responsive than creating one :D

Comment: So change all of the pixels into EM and then figure out the width of the screen etc with % ? :)

Comment: yes for fonts use EM for width and margin / paddings use %

Comment: if everything is already in em then you can just concentrate on the layout to convert it to % .. rest is all hit and try :) no fixed solution can be provided for these situations